# Groovy redundant trim() calls

Tags: java, string, groovy, trim

I'm reading a Groovy script and I'm finding a lot of trim() calls and especially this kind of expression:

```
x = "ok".trim()
```

I'm wondering if trim() apart from the obvious trimming has also some other effect that would explain the above expression (it can also be just bad code).

Comment: in this case: ```x = "ok".trim()
``` does not have any effect.

Comment: I know there is a String and a GString, could be some kind of conversion?

Comment: nope, trim removes white space before and after the text. e.g " ok   
     ".trim() will give you "ok" (without the spaces)

Comment: If your "ok" there is by some mean considereda GString (e.g. if there is `${..}` in it), then the trim() would act as a "golfed" `.toString()`. So maybe this can be attributed to poor copy-and-pasting or inlining? And since your code example there has no `def` in front of it, is this some special snowflake like jenkins, soapui, gradle, ... you did not mention?

Comment: There just a `def x = ...` somewhere above, it's just groovy used as a scripting language in a framework (nothing special)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default definition of `trim()` remove space from start and end of the string. So, In your app if you are using default definition then "ok".trim() does not has any effect.

But if you change the definition of `trim()` method then it is possible it will behave in a different way. Now String is a final class so you can't override it but Groovy gives you a feature called `metaclass` which allows you to change the definition at runtime.

Run the below code on the groovy [console](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/).

```
String.metaClass.trim = {
 //you could have your own trim implementation here for String class
 return "Hi"
}
x = "ok".trim()
println x
```

Output:

```
Hi
```

So, my conclusion is as soon as you are not changing the definition of trim() your code does not has any effect.

Comment: I grepped for metaClass, didn't find anything. But very interesting answer (If nothing else shows up I will accept it)

Comment: Yeah, someone isn't writing very clean code... I'd remove the trim